# VBA Sort ignored inside ElseIf

Tags: vba, sorting, if-statement

Could anyone please explain to me why it is that the line below that is trying to filter my data by E1 will not work in the first location (see "<<< 1st Location"), but it works fine in the second location (see "<<< 2nd Location"). No error thrown for the first location, it just seems to skip it.

```
Private Sub CommandButton31_Click()

Call CreateDataSheet

If ToggleButtonFrontTeam.Value = False And ComboBox1.Value = "Designer" Then
    Call FilterFrontTeamSortDesigner
    Sheets("Data_Sheet").Range("A2:I10000").Sort Key1:=Range("E1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo   '<<< 1st Location
ElseIf ToggleButtonMidTeam.Value = False And ComboBox1.Value = "Designer" Then
    Call FilterMidTeamSortDesigner

ElseIf ToggleButtonRearTeam.Value = False And ComboBox1.Value = "Designer" Then
    Call FilterRearTeamSortDesigner

Else
    Unload Me

End If

Sheets("Data_Sheet").Range("A2:I10000").Sort Key1:=Range("E1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo    '<<< 2nd Location

Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you add some info about the expression used in the IF  (`ToggleButtonFrontTeam.Value = False And ComboBox1.Value = "Designer"` ), does it evaluate to True ?

Comment: This is just asking IF a ToggleButton has been clicked and a ComboBox has a certain value, so yes I guess it must evaluate to True? These exist within a UserForm

Comment: Just the existence does of the Togglebutton and the ComboBox say nothing about their value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 2nd location sort is outside the if statement which gets executed regardless of what the if results are.

So your results will always be to the below sort.

```
Sheets("Data_Sheet").Range("A2:I10000").Sort Key1:=Range("E1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo    '<<< 2nd Location
```

Comment: The Sort in the 1st location and the 2nd are the exact same thing. What I am trying to do is move the Sort from outside the If statement to inside it, but it doesn't work there, it works fine outside the If, which is what is confusing me. Ideally I'd like to delete it from the 2nd location and only have it in the 1st location